# Updated ruby and rails gives error to .new .update methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

I have recently updated my ruby version and rails version.

```
ruby 1.9.3 to ruby 2.1.1
rails 3.2.6 to rails 4.0.0
```

Then installed following new gems

```
 protected_attributes(1.0.3)
 turbolinks(2.5.3)
```

While running code i got following error to create and update method.

Got **wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)** error at **.new, .update mehods**.
eg.

```
      **wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)**
      def create
        **@gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)**
        respond_to do |format|
         if @gallery.save
          format.html { redirect_to :back, :notice => t('notice.gallery_created') }
          format.json { render json: @gallery, status: :created, location: @gallery }
         else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
       end
    end

      private
      def gallery_params
            params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, :user_id, :description, images_attributes: [:title, :description, :image, :user_id])
      end
```

I am sending following parameters from my form.

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4DosQk69bQzV9idZapxjseVPNedORytYtNYH4rUCeBk=", "gallery"=>{"title"=>"test title 10", "description"=>"this is the gallery desription", "user_id"=>"1", "images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"test image", "description"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb48788b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160229-7649-3kw561>, @original_filename="564650_685411374823853_181629729_n.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"564650_685411374823853_181629729_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "user_id"=>"1"}}}, "commit"=>"Update", "locale"=>"en"}
```

It gives me error to every **form (form_for or nested_form_for) in my application.**

Tried following code in controller which saves my data but .new .update still have issue.
eg.

```
@gallery = Gallery.new
@gallery.title = "test title 10"
@gallery.description = "this is the gallery description"
@gallery.user_id =  1
@gallery.save
```

Comment: Check the rails version in your gem file

Comment: The params you are sending?

Comment: I have given that in answer because, it will be so big to write in a comment

Comment: probably an incompatible gem - full error backtrace might be helpful. Also, I would have thought you might as well update to at least the most recent 4.0.x version rather than 4.0.0 (and even then you'll still have unpatched security changes)

Comment: oks will update to recent 4.0 version and check again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def gallery_params
  params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, :user_id, :description, images_attributes: [:title, :description, :image, :user_id])
end
```

Comment: Sorry this not helped me

Answer (score 0):

Once try like this and let us see if the issue is in strong parameters

```
def create
        @gallery = Gallery.new({"title"=>"test title 10", "description"=>"this is the gallery desription", "user_id"=>"1", "images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"test image", "description"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb48788b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160229-7649-3kw561>, @original_filename="564650_685411374823853_181629729_n.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"564650_685411374823853_181629729_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "user_id"=>"1"}}})
        respond_to do |format|
         if @gallery.save
          format.html { redirect_to :back, :notice => t('notice.gallery_created') }
          format.json { render json: @gallery, status: :created, location: @gallery }
         else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
       end
    end
```

Comment: tried above line and Gallery.new(:title =>"test title 10", :description =>"this is the gallery desription", :user_id=>"1"), still gives same result